# How do I post a Link to Facebook without a thumbnail?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to post a Link to Facebook using the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post), but I'd like to be able to avoid a thumbnail image.  Facebook's web interface has a no-thumbail checkbox while posting an image; I'd like to simulate this from my own application.

I've tried specifying an empty string for both the `source` and `picture` arguments, but Facebook still fetches a thumbnail image for the specified `link` regardless.

For example, I've tried this, but a thumbnail image still shows up:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Link with empty source and empty picture' \
     -F 'link=http://stackoverflow.com' \
     -F 'picture=' \
     -F 'source=' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

*UPDATE: [This support forum](http://community.dlvr.it/dlvrit/topics/unwanted_facebook_thumbnails) suggests that this is a bug with Facebook, and they suggest posting a 1x1 pixel clear image.  I'd prefer a better workaround than this.*

Comment: I created a Facebook bug in the new bug tracking system about this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/231434760243248

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has now fixed this [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/224089347649919). Set picture to empty string or set picture=NULL, both should work now.

Comment: unfortunately it is not fixed for posting to "me/links"

Answer (score 5):

Since `picture=0` no longer seems to work without throwing an error, here's another way, but it's a hack and not likely recommended.  By skipping the `picture` argument and specifying a `source` argument that is a valid URL, but isn't an image, Facebook will render the post without the thumbnail.  For example:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Link with empty source and empty picture' \
     -F 'link=http://cnn.com' \
     -F 'source=http://cnn.com' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

Comment: That seems to work... but you're right that it feels hacky. I was just neglecting to include a picture, but just today it has started intermittently returning success with no image or {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#100) img objects must have valid 'src' and 'href' attributes"}} or including an image from the page. I'm thinking they're mucking with it again and not getting it right :-(

Comment: Oddly enough, if you query for the post created by this method, neither the picture nor the source attributes exist.

Answer (score 2):

I talked with Facebook developers at F8 2011 and they agreed that this is a bug. I have filed this bug with Facebook in their new bug tracking system:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/231434760243248

If you want it fixed, upvote this question & answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the value "0" for picture.  This worked for us, it does show a gray bar next to the link information, but it doesn't pull in a default image and doesn't display the awkward whitespace when using a 1x1 pixel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Bummer. I had to remove this as the accepted answer, because Facebook no longer allows this.  If you try `picture=0`, Facebook returns the following nonsensical error: **(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream**

Answer (score 0):

Now in June 2011 it seems the "picture=" parameter isn't required at all, and FB didn't pull one from the page either:

```
curl \
     -F "message=test message, attempting to verify solution of SO problem" \
     -F "name=StackOverflow" \
     -F "link=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246170/how-do-i-post-a-link-to-facebook-without-a-thumbnail" \
     -F "access_token=you_dont|reallythink|imgonnapostmyrealaccesstoken_doya?" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com/11239244970/feed"
```

Result at SO's Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/stackoverflow/11239244970

Comment: Great, Facebook's API changes again. Is this behavior documented somewhere now, or is another hidden change? I'm just worried about relying on this if they choose to "fix" it back to the way it used to work. For example, we're still using the clear image hack just to ensure our customers get the desired behavior all the time.  

See this too: https://skitch.com/rmm5t/fruhy/no-thumbnail-graphapi

Comment: maybe undocumented, at least not mentioned in the online Graph API documentation. I get the impression that the API is for Facebook's own use, and they couldn't really care less if anybody else is able to use it. probably better stick with the transparent pixel. an ugly hack that works is sometimes the best possible solution.

Comment: I'm getting intermittent problems using the method of not including a picture tag. Sometimes it throws an error back at me, other times it actually pulls in an image. :-(

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you specify a picture url where either the server is unreachable or the picture does not exist, the resulting post includes the grey bar as desired:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
-F 'message=404 picture' \
-F 'link=http://example.com' \
-F 'name=Example' \
-F 'description=example.com is not about bbq' \
-F 'caption=example.com' \
-F 'picture=http://example.com/this/does/not/exist/1.gif' \
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/
```

For full disclosure however, I'm not using this solution in production because it seems hacky and I don't trust Facebook to allow this method to exist indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

put an invalid url image it's will "resolve" while the facebook not fix this bug.
the parameter is: "picture"

Answer (score 0):

This had been disabled by Facebook and it's not a bug, it's by design as it's stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/155722798122148/) by the FB team. They say they will remove the "No thumbnail" option from their site too, not just on the API. The thread I linked is the most recent (31 Dec 2015).

The only option that works now is by sending the field `picture` with the url to a 1x1 pixel image.