# How can I post a link to Facebook without thumbnail preview?

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on Facebook without thumbnail, but even if I set `$link_img` to `null` Facebook takes the default image.

```
$facebookReturn = $fb->add_post
                     ->set_message($message)
                     ->set_link_uri($link_url)
                     ->set_link_name($link_title)
                     ->set_link_description($link_desc)
                     ->set_picture_uri($link_img)
                     ->publish;
```

How can I tell Facebook not to post the thumbnail?

I am using Facebook's Perl API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I post a Link to Facebook without a thumbnail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246170/how-do-i-post-a-link-to-facebook-without-a-thumbnail)

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a post containing an image, Facebook will display a thumbnail. This is just how Facebook currently works.

There is no way to change or alter Facebook's behavior with regard to how they display posts containing images.

If you don't want a thumbnail, then you shouldn't post an image with the post. Just have the link. That being said, with only a link, Facebook will attempt to extract a thumbnail image from the provided link - so you might have to deal with that as well.